# CSS change content only on one element

Tags: html, css, text, replace, css-selectors

i have the following html snippet:

```
<div class="account_button account_button2">Login</div>
```

Now i want to change that content ("Login") only with CSS. (Because im not allowed to change HTML files, i can only write an CSS Overwrite file)

So i changed the content with this css code:

```
.account_button {
    visibility: hidden;
} 

.account_button:after {
    content: 'Login / Register';
    visibility: visible;
}
```

This works absolutely well. But now the tricky part.

The mentioned html snipped is changed via Javascript, if an User is already logged in to the following (span Element is added to html):

```
<div class="account_button account_button2"><span>Username</span></div>
```

My CSS Overwrite will also Overwrite that Value. How can i avoid this? I only want to change the Value of the DIV-Element, not the SPAN element which is added via Javascript in case of some conditions.

THANKS for any idea!

Edit: A little clarification:
I got two "html states":

1.)

```
<div class="account_button account_button2">Login</div>
```

This is changed via above css to display "Login / Register".

2.)

```
<div class="account_button account_button2"><span>Username</span></div>
```

If JS changed the html to this, the above CSS will also display "Login / Register". I want it to display the value within the span tags in case there are existing. If they not exist, i would like to display "Login / Register".

Comment: Unfortunately there is no parent selector in CSS. Seems you need JavaScript

Comment: At CSS level you will need to know if the user has logged in or not. There's no way around that. The login JS must be modded to toggle some CSS class indicating the login state of the user (if there isn't already some class defined). Also, I doubt that your current solution *works absolutely well*, as the hidden text may not be visible alright, it still occupies space of 'Login' text length.

Comment: Thank you for your information. So there is no way of doing this only via CSS?
It works, so it always shows "Login / Register" regardless if <span> tag is added or the value is just within <div> tags...
What i need is an way to tell css "only change the content for div, but not if span is added in the div".. :-/

Comment: You could use absolute positioning for the span, so that when span is being added, it will overlay the other set text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use absolute positioning for the span, so that when span is being added, it will overlay the other set text?

I set up the following example which could help:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xphszdjr/)

```
.account_button {
  background: red;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.account_button span {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
 }
```

Could this fix your problem?

Update: Setting width for button:

```
<div class="account_button account_button2">Login <span>Username</span> </div>
<div class="account_button account_button2">Login </div>

.account_button {
  background: red;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.account_button::before {
  content: 'Login/Register';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

.account_button span {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;

 }
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/hL3rmnt1/)

This fixes it?
Update 3:
Adding height and line-height:

```
<div class="account_button account_button2"><span>Username</span> </div>
<br>
<div class="account_button account_button2">Login </div>
.account_button {
  background: red;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.account_button::before {
  content: 'Login/Register';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.account_button span {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;

 }
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hL3rmnt1/1/) example

Like this?

Comment: If span is added the span value should be shown.

So no span set: Overwrite default html "Login" with "Login / Register". Span is set (So user is already logged in) CSS should not overwrite the default html "Login / Register" instead it should show the span value (Which is filled with Username via JS)
is it somehow possible to tell CSS only to change div but dont touch if span is within that div element?

Comment: If you can/want set a fixed width to the button you could do as follow:
https://jsfiddle.net/hL3rmnt1/

Comment: Thank you for your help!
But i will not have this case: "<div class="account_button account_button2">Login <span>Username</span> </div>"
instead, i will have this: "<div class="account_button account_button2"><span>Username</span></div>"
(I edited my first post to make it clearer)

Comment: Add height and line-height to the button: https://jsfiddle.net/hL3rmnt1/1/

Comment: THANK YOU very much! Now i got what you try to tell me! ;-) Maybe it is not the "cleanest" solution - but i got it working! Thank you.
I will run some tests and let you know if this is an solution for me

Comment: Would be a lot easier and 'cleaner' with js instead of css hack.